# Start activity after Toast message

Tags: android, android-intent, toast

When my Activity don't get data from the DB, I show a Toast message saying about this. Then I recharge the previous Activity but this charge very fast and the Toast message still there a few seconds. I want this message duration but I don't know how to retard the init of the Activity that I want to start after message.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
setContentView(R.layout.aeiou);

...

if(!oArrayList.isEmpty()){

    ...

}else{          
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "NO hay datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreviousActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);   
}
```

}

Comment: Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "NO hay datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Change the Toast.LENGTH_LONG. You can use mils instead of static toast method duration.

Comment: Thanks but I have the same problem with the message, is there when the next Activity starts. And the duration of message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, is good for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the "else" I added a thread that sleeps while Toast message is showing and after starts the next Activity.

```
...}else{           
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "NO hay datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);        

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
                try {
                   Thread.sleep(3500); // As I am using LENGTH_LONG in Toast
                   startActivity(intent);   
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           } 
        };

        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys. I found this way, and works. What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know , the duration of the toast can only be set of one of two values (long and short) , both can be user defined.

in order to set your own time and also be notified when it's over , you will need to create your own mechanism instead of the built in toast ...

try to use either a dialog (maybe progressDialog) or create a view that will be on top of all of the others.

Answer (score 2):

```
Toast.makeText(this, "your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

(new Handler())
    .postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    // launch your activity here
    }
    }, timeInMillisecondTheToastIsShowingFor);
```

This will delay launching the activity for however long you'd like